# Google Maia .css and .js files?

Tags: javascript, css

I recently stumbled across the Google .css and. js files by the name of "Google Maia". These appear to be an in-the-works competitor / replacement for Twitter's Bootstrap. Does anyone know where to find the official version?

Comment: This is off topic as it's about finding an off-site resource.

Answer (score 5):

As of now its internal. Google hasn't released any version for public yet https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/closure-library-discuss/YzmT7G1AqQg .
 However you can get some clue from google style sheet guide https://google-styleguide.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/htmlcssguide.xml

Answer (score 0):

This is most likely an internal resource for Google, not publicly available.